# Looping through multidimensional arrays and adding tax query for each taxonomy

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I'm getting values from a resource form that has different taxonomies. Each taxonomy has several different terms. With these taxonomies and terms I'm running a query to get specific posts and returning the results via a function and ajax.

In the function I'm grabbing all the parameters and trying to see if the parameters have the same taxonomy and if so check if there's multiple terms submitted and add in a tax query. I've managed to created a multidimensional array grouped with the same taxonomy and I'm dumping this out:

```
array (size=3)
  'resource-format' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'resource-format' (length=15)
          'value' => string '83' (length=2)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'resource-format' (length=15)
          'value' => string '81' (length=2)
  'resource-author' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'resource-author' (length=15)
          'value' => string '73' (length=2)
  'resource-origin' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'resource-origin' (length=15)
          'value' => string '89' (length=2)
```

for each taxonomy I'd like to add this tax query, but make sure all the values for a specific taxonomy are in 1 call.

```
$filter_args['tax_query'][] = array(
           'taxonomy' => $param[name],
           'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $param[value]
);
```

So for the above I'm basically looking for resource format to be

```
$filter_args['tax_query'][] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'resource-format,
           'field' => 'id',
           'terms' => (83,81),
);
```

and also have:

```
$filter_args['tax_query'][] = array(
           'taxonomy' => 'resource-author,
           'field' => 'id',
           'terms' => (73),
);
```

I'm having trouble putting all this together. Any insights would be great.